# How to review an extension to an answer

Tags: discussion, review, edits

This is a minor issue, but I was uncertain how to react to it, so I am bringing this topic to meta.

This is the question and answer I was uncertain of:

[What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts/7286331#7286331)

There was an edit made, which added the text in italics:

> Shift+Delete deletes the entire line *(will 'cut' it to clipboard)*

While I agree that it is the correct, I was not sure what to do with it, because I thought that the answer's author should be the one to make the change. But then again, I know that the edit was correct.

Should I have accepted it?

Comment: Will someone care to explain the downvotes? I am trying to do my best here at SO, and since I'm relatively fresh here, I don't know everything. Why is this question wrong? What should I have asked? I feel like being scolded for trying to be a better member of the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if it was correct, why would you not accept it? There is a difference between formatting and vandalism and a little italics to point emphasis at the outcome of an action could help future readers. This is where the 2K+ reputation holders on Stack Overflow show their worth. We are expected to read, comprehend, and decipher edits made to other posts. If you are unsure of an edit, skip it and let someone else who is sure make the vote.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that the edit was correct.

Then what's the problem? Approve it.

> I thought that the answer's author should be the one to make the change

No. If that is the case then what is the purpose of editing other's post?

> I was not sure what to do with it

There is a big button called <kbd>Skip</kbd>. Just press it.

[image]

Comment: I always thought that the prupose of editing is to fix technical issues in a post: code formatting, fixing old links, grammar and language corrections. The forbidden changes, I thought, were: interfering with the content, like changing code, removing/adding content to answers, and all the other vandalism and spam changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would have accepted it, and likely edited to improve by changing 'delete' to 'cut'. It adds some useful context and makes the answer better.

If you want to get language lawyer-y it does change the answer, from *wrongish* to *right*.

<sub>(*ed: I've ignored the usefulness of the question and answers as a whole.*)</sub>

Comment: I just realized you went and added it yourself...if *you* would add it to a post then yes, you should accept the edit.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the idea of comments, to improve the answer.

Comment: From my perspective, the idea of comments are to provide either a caveat (not improve) to the answer or to inform the question or answer OP of potential flaws in the post (i.e. "Hey bro, you missed a closing bracket")

Comment: @ChristopherW Is it written somewhere? I couldn't find any community guidelines on that matter.

Comment: @Dariusz, I added "from my perspective".

Comment: From my perspective this whole comment exchange is odd because I too am Christopher W and would have said exactly what he did. Where is a mind==blown emoticon when you need one...